# What does そんなところでいい mean here?

Tags: meaning

> **サラーキア**
> 「私も私でやることはあるけど……貴方ほど目まぐるしい忙しさはないし、いいわよ。引き受けるわ」
>
> **Guy1**
> 「助かる」
>
> **ルキナ**
> 「すまぬなサラーキア。　面倒をかけてしまいそうじゃ」
>
> ルキナの言葉に、サラーキアは頭を下げて答えた。
>
> **Guy1**
> 「今は**そんなところでいい**だろう。進捗状況は随時連絡してくれ。こちらも効果のありそうなネタが入手できたら渡す」
>
> **サラーキア**
> 「わかったわ。どこまで力になれるか分からないけどやれるだけの事はやってみましょう」

In this exchange I'm uncertain of what he means by そんなところでいい, or rather what そんなところ is referring to. I think he is talking about the current situation (he is too busy to help, so she currently has to do it alone, possibly in the future when they have more progress/he has more time  he will help). Can anyone clarify this for me?

Comment: I think your interpretation is correct. I am curious about the context, from where is that dialog extracted from?

Answer (score 1):

Unless the larger context proves otherwise, the following could be said pretty safely.

「そんなところ」 refers to the situation as it stands with a promise to help from サラーキア.

「そんなところでいい」 means that this situation is at least satisfactory, if not great.

「[今]{いま}は」 would suggest that the speaker (Guy1) expects the situation to possibly improve in the (near) future.